# getting 400 bad request error when nginx reverse proxy is configured with SSL.

Tags: ssl, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have configured Nginx reverse proxy server to listen on port 443 and pass the requests to an upstream SAAS client. Below is the configuration.

```
server {
listen 443;
server_name test.saas.someloggingserver.com;

ssl on;
ssl_certificate C:/nginx-1.13.8/nginx-1.13.8/ssl/server_cert.crt;
ssl_certificate_key C:/nginx-1.13.8/nginx-1.13.8/ssl/server.key;

ssl_session_timeout  5m;
ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers  ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

expires 0;
add_header Cache-Control private;

access_log logs/encrypted_access.txt;
    error_log logs/encrypted_error.txt debug;

location / {
    proxy_set_header    Host $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_redirect      http:// https://;
proxy_pass          https://test.saas.someloggingserver.com;
}
}
```

The SSL certificate here also includes a intermediate certificate for SSL handshaking with the upstream server. Now when I try to access the https://test.saas.someloggingserver.com from IE (having above proxy configured) I get below 400 bad request error. I am no Nginx debugging expert, appreciate if you can take a look at below logs and direct me towards the possible cause of this issue?

```
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: post event 02D76250
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: delete posted event 02D76250
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: accept on 0.0.0.0:443, ready: 0
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: malloc: 02D50808:256
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 accept: 10.92.67.192:49268 fd:496
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 event timer add: 496: 60000:2616257381
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 reusable connection: 1
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 select add event fd:496 ev:0
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 post event 02D76340
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 delete posted event 02D76340
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 http check ssl handshake
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 http recv(): 1
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 plain http
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 http wait request handler
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 malloc: 02D4CF80:1024
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 WSARecv: fd:496 rc:0 266 of 1024
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 reusable connection: 0
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 malloc: 02DAF920:4096
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 http process request line
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [info] 14640#9400: *3695 client sent invalid request while reading client request line, client:        10.92.67.192, server: test.saas.someloggingserver.com, request: "CONNECT test.saas.someloggingserver.com:443 HTTP/1.0"
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 http finalize request: 400, "?" a:1, c:1
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 event timer del: 496: 2616257381
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 http special response: 400, "?"
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 http set discard body
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx/1.13.8
Date: Thu, 28 Dec 2017 07:04:45 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 173
Connection: close

2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 write new buf t:1 f:0 02DB0018, pos 02DB0018, size: 152 file: 0, size: 0
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 http write filter: l:0 f:0 s:152
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 http output filter "?"
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 http copy filter: "?"
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 http postpone filter "?" 02DB017C
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 write old buf t:1 f:0 02DB0018, pos 02DB0018, size: 152 file: 0, size: 0
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 write new buf t:0 f:0 00000000, pos 00F25C68, size: 120 file: 0, size: 0
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 write new buf t:0 f:0 00000000, pos 00F25758, size: 53 file: 0, size: 0
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 http write filter: l:1 f:0 s:325
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 http write filter limit 0
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 WSASend: fd:496, s:325
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 http write filter 00000000
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 http copy filter: 0 "?"
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 http finalize request: 0, "?" a:1, c:1
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 event timer add: 496: 5000:2616202381
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 post event 02D76340
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 delete posted event 02D76340
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 http lingering close handler
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 WSARecv: fd:496 rc:0 0 of 4096
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 lingering read: 0
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 http request count:1 blk:0
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 http close request
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 http log handler
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 free: 02DAF920, unused: 1771
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 close http connection: 496
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 event timer del: 496: 2616202381
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 select del event fd:496 ev:0
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 reusable connection: 0
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 free: 02D4CF80
2017/12/28 07:04:45 [debug] 14640#9400: *3695 free: 02D50808, unused: 28
```

Comment: Both domain names are same? The one nginx is hosted and one that it proxy passes to?

Comment: No, they are different. Nginx is hosted on-premises, while the server it passes traffic to is an SAAS model for us.

Comment: Then you should remove `proxy_set_header    Host $host;`, because that sends your hosted host name to SAAS which is not aware of it and neither expecting it

Comment: Thanks Tarun for pointing out. I have commented out this line, but still seeing the same error as shared initially. I am sure i might had to deal with this host header issue at a later point.

Comment: How do you browser the SAAS url in the browser? Does it work directly. If it does then you should try with just `proxy_pass` as the only step and see if that helps

Comment: Yes, so when nginx is listening on port 80 with simple proxy_pass set up. It works fine. In the browser proxy settings i put the proxy ip and port as 80 to access the SAAS url. But when nginx is listening on 443 port it throws 400 bad request. Again i have put the proxy ip in browser setting with port no as 443 to access the SAAS url.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162119/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-krishan-kant).

Comment: Thanks Tarun. As you pointed out, the set up was wrong. I now have used Apache as a forward proxy and it now is working fine. Thanks a ton mate.

Comment: Posted the details as answer. I had not worked much with Apache, so this is something good to know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Apache as a Forward Proxy, because nginx can only be used as a reverse proxy or as a http proxy.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#forwardreverse

> An ordinary forward proxy is an intermediate server that sits between the client and the origin server. In order to get content from the origin server, the client sends a request to the proxy naming the origin server as the target. The proxy then requests the content from the origin server and returns it to the client. The client must be specially configured to use the forward proxy to access other sites.
>
> A typical usage of a forward proxy is to provide Internet access to internal clients that are otherwise restricted by a firewall. The forward proxy can also use caching (as provided by mod_cache) to reduce network usage.

**Forward Proxy**

```
ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia On

<Proxy "*">
  Require host internal.example.com
</Proxy>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in one reply, I also faced the same issue with nginx setup so we have done the setup using Apache and wrote a article for the community about steps, which worked for us. Please check it out - https://medium.com/@gaurav.k.sarawgi/use-apache-to-create-forward-proxy-server-on-ubuntu-3299ef91a7cb